# Shiny leaflet - points not plotted when layerId is set

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a Shiny app with a leaflet map. I need to be able to set a `layerId` value on the map for my full app. However, when I do that, most of my points disappear. If I remove the `layerId`, all my points are displayed correctly. Any help would be highly appreciated...

Minimum example below - comment out the `layerId` line to see the issue I'm having.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- structure(list(Lon = c(-111.279, -111.388, -111.441, -111.899, 
-111.189, -111.182, -111.151, -111.146, -111.131, -111.109, -111.474
), Lat = c(43.864, 44.055, 44.176, 44.727, 43.809, 43.807, 43.805, 
43.811, 43.812, 43.816, 44.259)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


leaflet(df) %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Lon, lat = ~Lat,
            layerId = "1") ### <----- problem child here
```

Comment: Hard to know what you want without context. Read show/hide layers on https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html

Comment: I want to have all my points shown, with an assigned `layerID` value. It's a single layer, so I'm not sure that the reference is helpful here. Why assigning a `layerID` value makes a most of the points of the layer disappear? If you run the code with and without the last line, you'll see what the issue is.

Comment: I know what the problem is, but I don't know do you need layerID or group parameter (depending on what the use case is). LayerID needs to have same length as number of points and unique values. Just read group vs layerID on page, everything is nicely explained.

Comment: Ohhhh, I've been totally misreading every. single. layerID. explanation for 2 days now. Sigh... I needed to assign a layerId to be able to remove layers in an animation. But now I see that I need to either work with `group` or vectorize the `layerId`. Thanks for the pointer... If you write up an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: yeah depending on what the use case is. Answer is below regarding layerID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  leaflet() %>%  
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Lon, lat = ~Lat, layerId = ~id)
```